# NativeScript best way of saving favorites

Tags: storage, nativescript, applicationsettingsbase

I am looking for correct and decent way of storing favorites articles in my app to phone storage. I built the app with Web shop articles listed and I would like to allow users to save favorite articles to the "favorite" list.

I have tried  `application-settings` plugin and I am not sure is this a good way of doing it because keys needs to be predefined. (I am not really sure). 
Is there a some kind of JSON style data storage which does work on Android and iOS? - It would be great because I could sync it to Cloud storage at some point.

I need a easy way for manipulating data, add, remove, clear the list. Something what will not impact app performance. 
Cheers guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's entirely up to you to choose one of below. I would say you should be good with `application-settings` itself.

[application-settings](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/application-settings) is still a quick and good option.

```
function getFavorites() {
  return applicationSettings.getString("favorites", "[]");
}

function setFavorites(data) {
  return applicationSettings.setString("favorites", JSON.stringify(data));
}

let data = getFavorites();

// Add new
data.push({
    id: "NewFavId",
    ... // other attributes
});

// Delete existing one
data = data.filter((item) => item.id === "IdToDelete");


// Update application settings
setFavorites(data);
```

[nativescript-localstorage](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-localstorage) is another similar option which internally uses JSON files to store data.

Speaking of storing data on device, [nativescript-sqlite](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-sqlite) is also there but you may not need this for simple data operations like yours Or [nativescript-secure-storage](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-secure-storage) which is again another option but only to be used for storing highly sensitive information.

Comment: Hi @Manoj, this looks great, I was not thinking about this in this way. Looks like that sqlite requires much more code for this simple manipulation. Thanks!